# Xamarin - Replacing the Action Bar (Android 7.1 - API 25)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

I have tried creating a toolbar by replacing the default actionbar exactly as detailed in the documentation : [Part 1 - Replacing the Action Bar](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/), but the app doesn't run and throws an error at `SetActionBar(toolbar);`. The following is the error message:

```
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set android:windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

the following is the full error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set android:windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

Here is the git repo of all my code : 
[Github CustomAndroidToolBar](https://github.com/McKabue/CustomAndroidToolBar)

am using visual studio enterpise 2017, version 15.5

**Where am i going wrong?**

Comment: Seems like you did not create a custom theme to exclude the default action bar `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/controls/tool-bar/part-1-replacing-the-action-bar/#custom_theme

Comment: it is there in https://github.com/McKabue/CustomAndroidToolBar/blob/50839f8582e904d35e558cb21f9406a4e720db49/App3/Resources/values/styles.xml#L5

Comment: Not debugging offsite resources, but delete the apk from the emulator/device and perform a clean/rebuild

Comment: it still returns the same error: `Unhandled Exception:

Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR and set android:windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead. occurred`

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/theming-with-appcompat-1a292b754b35 - TLDR; Use a `Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar` theme if you are providing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Xamarin - Replacing the Action Bar (Android 7.1 - API 25)

There is some error in your project.

**First, please read this [official sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/Supportv7/AppCompat/Toolbar/Supportv7Toolbar/Resources/values/styles.xml), you are using some wrong item.** You should use

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">
```

instead of

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">.
```

Modify your `style.xml` like this :

```
<!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <!--We will be using the toolbar so no need to show ActionBar-->
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <!-- Set theme colors from http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-palette-->
    <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated
     which is used to tint widgets -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
 </style>
```

---

**Second, Install `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` nuget package** :

[image]

Then extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity` for you `MainActivity`, and  [use a `Theme.AppCompat` theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity).

Please note that **although you have written a custom theme in your project, you didn't use it for your `MainActivity`**. You could read the document : [Theming an Activity](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/material-theme/#Theming_an_Activity), add the theme for you `MainActivity` :

```
[Activity(Label = "App3", MainLauncher = true, Theme = "@style/MyTheme")]
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    ...
}
```

---

Third, in your project you are using `Android.Widget.Toolbar`, please change it to `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar`.

In your `MainActivity` :

```
var toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

if (toolbar != null)
{
    SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    SupportActionBar.Title = "Hello from Appcompat Toolbar";
}
```

In your `toolbar.xml` :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
```

Then it works fine on my side.